# How does hibernate know to persist data passed to the entity class via a setter?

Tags: hibernate

I have gone through various blogs, documentations, tutorials.. But i am not getting the internal thing happening in hibernate like **How does hibernate know to persist data passed to the entity class via a setter?**

Please suggest me the documentation or anything related or any answers.

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism Hibernate use to generate query is call **dirty checking**. By default once you load an record from the database Hibernate will store a snapshot of the entity in the persistence context and give you a **managed entity**.

At flush time the framework will check entity states (managed, transient or removed) and make a diff between every managed entity properties and the corresponding snapshot to generate insert, update and delete query .

This is the default dirty checking strategy, which have some CPU and memory footprint. You can reduce it with some mechanism like the use of the [`@Imumutable`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Immutable.html) annotation.

Another option is to use [bytecode enhancement for automatic dirty check](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/pc/BytecodeEnhancement.html). With this strategy each entity will keep record of what changed inside and at flush time Hibernate will just ask every entity what changed.

Hope it helped !

Answer (score 0):

The DB credentials will be passed through hibernate.cfg.xml file, such as driver class, url, username, password, dialect, hbm2ddl.auto etc.

Inside the pojo class, `@Table(name="table_name")` is used to get access to a table in DB.

Each variable in the pojo class is annotated with `@column(name="column_name")`. The variables points towards the corresponding columns in table. If you want to declare a variable , which is not there in DB table, annotate it by using @Transient.

Now when you create the pojo class object, then setting the data to object using setter, each variable inside the pojo for that object is initialised with some value and same time the variable is pointing to particular columns.

So when you call `persist()` or `save()` or `saveOrUpdate()` method by passing the object, the values of the variables will be entered to the proper columns.

After calling persists or save or saveOrUpdate, you must call `commit()`

Comment: Go to youtube. Search  "hibernate tutorials by durgasoft" . A video series of 35 videos are there, by Naveen.